# Flat Normal Map in Cycles (not Eevee)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

I have a  strange problem with Normal Map in Cycles. It's look flat, but when I switch on Eevee, it's look well, as I make in Sub...
(Is this name not forbidden here? =))

Here examples (Note the pattern and handle.):
**Cycles:**
[image]

**Eevee:**
[image]

Blender 2.82 Steam.

Material Nodes:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of you material nodes?

Comment: Added in topic.