# Normal maps look different in Cycles vs. Cycles + OSL vs. Eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

I was rendering a model with a normal map with Cycles in Blender 3.1.2 and noticed that the result looks different from the result in Eevee.

The result is similar to the Stackexchange issues described in:

[Flat Normal Map in Cycles (not Eevee)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174053/flat-normal-map-in-cycles-not-eevee)

[Why do the results from normal maps differ between Eevee and Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224454/why-do-the-results-from-normal-maps-differ-between-eevee-and-cycles)

So to investigate the problem I created a new scene and added simple plane, one point light, and I removed the world background entirely as to have no ambient lighting whatsoever. I then added a normal map to the plane. I rendered the result in Evee, Cycles with the default shading, and Cycles with OSL shading. I created the following node setup for the normal map with the image color space set to "Non-color".

The blend file can be found here: [image]

Node setup:
[image]

Rendered result in Eevee:
[image: Eevee render]

Rendered result in Cyles *without* OSL:
[image]

Rendered result in Cyles *with* OSL:
[image]

As you can see the result in the default shading mode in Cycles is different and the result in Eevee and Cycles OSL is the same. Also when I turn on Cycles\Eevee in the viewport and change the viewpoint the shading changes in Cycles with the default shading mode. It looks as if there is a light coming from the camera. What causes this issue? Can this be a bug?

Comment: Looks like bug. I haven't found any clues in tracker. Maybe caused by this https://developer.blender.org/T94737, but not sure. If you don't mind, I can report.

Comment: I don't see the jagged artifacts as described in T94737, my issue is like described in https://developer.blender.org/T56209 but there the issue is in OSL while my issue is without OSL. I would not mind reporting it, but feel free to report it. Please let me know ticket number if you do, I'm interested in updates.

Comment: Reported here: https://developer.blender.org/T98163

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: It should be fixed with https://developer.blender.org/rB8fdd3aad9bd8bd463b9b792f0d9063c2330aadfa

Comment: @Crantisz Although they closed your bug report but I tested in in Blender 3.2 with the fix and Eevee is still different from Cycles. They made it so that regular shading and OSL are the same in Cycles but Eevee is correct. In Cycles it look like there are two lights in the scene which is incorrect, in Eevee there is only one light which is correct. Can you open your bug report or can anyone create tickets on developer.blender.org?